# 500 Internal Server Error Laravel & ionic/angular

Tags: angular, laravel, ionic-framework

I am developing a application using ionic/angular as FrontEnd and laravel as backend, so my post request in  Laravel it successfully works in Postman but ,I am getting error (500 Internal Server Error) when I add the post from ionic/angular

image of postman
[image: image of postman]

**this is postController:**

```
 public function store(Request $request)
{
    $post = new post();
    $post->id             = $request->id             ;  
    $post->title          = $request->title          ;
    $post->description    = $request->description    ;
    $post->price          = $request->price          ;   
    $post->category_id          = $request->category_id  ;  
    $post->user_id          = $request->user_id      ; 
   
    //upload image
if($request->hasFile('picture')){
    //Storage::delete('/public/pictures/'.$user->picture);
    // Get filename with the extension
    $filenameWithExt = $request->file('picture')->getClientOriginalName();
    //Get just filename
    $filename = pathinfo($filenameWithExt, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
    $extension = $request->file('picture')->getClientOriginalExtension();
    // Filename to store
    $fileNameToStore = $filename.'_'.time().'.'.$extension;
    // Upload Image
    $path = $request->file('picture')->storeAs('public/images',$fileNameToStore);
    $post->picture = $fileNameToStore ;
    $post->save(); 
}
if($post->save())
{
 return new PostResource($post); 
}
  }
```

**this is PostService.ts**

```
apiData='http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/post/add';
constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }
insertData(post)
{
return this.http.post<IPost[]>(this.apiData , post);
}
```

**this is post.ts**

```
ngOnInit():void {
this.getAllCategorie();
this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
  title:[null,Validators.required],
  price: [0,Validators.required],
  description:[null,Validators.required],
  picture:[null,Validators.required],
  category_id:this.formBuilder.group({
     name: [Validators.required]
  })
});
 }

onSubmit():void {
 console.log(this.form.value);
    const dataPost  = this.form.value ;
     const categories = this.form.value.category_id.name ;
     const newPost = (
       dataPost.title , 
       dataPost.price,
       dataPost.description,
       categories 
       );
  this.servicePost.insertData(this.form.value).subscribe(res=>{
  this.post = res ;  
  console.log(res);

       })
        }
```

**this is post.html**

```
<ion-content>
<h1>Ajouter Annonce :</h1>
<form [formGroup]="form" >
<div class="form-group">
  <label>titre</label>
  <input formControlName="title" name="title" type="text" class="form-control" id="title" 
 placeholder="Enter titre de votre annonce">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label>Prix</label>
  <input formControlName="price" type="text" class="form-control" name="price" id="price" 
placeholder="Price">
</div>


 <div formGroupName="category_id">
<select class="custom-select" formControlName="name">
  <option selected >categories</option>
  <option *ngFor="let categorie of categories"  [value]="categorie.name"> {{categorie.name}} 
 </option>
 </select>
 </div>
  <div class="form-group">
   <label>Description</label>
   <input formControlName="description" name="description" type="text" class="form-control" 
    id="description" placeholder="description">
   </div>

<div class="custom-file">
  <input type="file" name="picture" class="form-control" id="picture" required 
(change)="uploadImage($event)" [ngClass]="{'is-invalid':submitted && f.picture.errors}">  <!-- >
  <div class="image-preview" *ngIf="imagePreview">
 <img [src]="imagePreview" alt="">
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="submitted && f.picture.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
    <div *ngIf="f.picture.errors.required">Image is required</div>
  </div>
</div>

<button (click)="onSubmit()" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" expand="block">Ajouter Annonce </button>
```

image of error
[image: image of error]

Comment: check your `category_id` in your laravel code. you are sending this as array and in your server you are expecting it as string. convert your `category_id` in your php code as array. it will work.

Comment: Please take a look at your Log files, the error should be logged there

Comment: @NajamUsSaqib i convert it like this $post->category_id    = $request['category_id']    but it is the same error

Comment: somewhere in your storage folder is a logs folder there should be a log file which points to the exact line in your code where the error is